# Display link to each other in navagation

Tags: html, css

I tried several times, `float: right` or `display: inline-block`, but it didn't work on my side. Can anyone guys help me to achieve it? I want to display my navigation next to each other just like below.[image: The words "Subscribe", "Contact Us", and "Resources" in a row.]

I tried to run several codes just what I mention above. But seems it need your help to work it properly.

```css
.menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 11px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin-right: 6rem;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}

ul li .link {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.head {
  position: relative;
  text-align: right;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 22px 48px 25px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
 }

 div .logopix {
  height: 5rem;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0;
  top: 1.1rem;
  left: 37px;
  position: absolute;


 }
```

```html
<div class="head">
        <img class="logopix" src="./images/logo.png" alt="HUB Motivator Logo" >
        <ul class="menu">
          <li class="link"> <a href="#">About</a> </li>
          <li class="link"> <a href="#">Contact Us</a> </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

add css in

```
.menu {
        display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Following same technique as you used with inline-block, to display li on same line add:

```
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Here is the code: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/AugustinF/pen/vRRwNm?editors=1100)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same requirement by writing very minimal semantic code and styling. Please check the code below.

Semantic HTML code

```
<header class="header">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x60"/>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <a href="/about">About</a>
    <a href="/services">Services</a>
    <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

CSS Style

```
.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar a {
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

View Demo : [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/prakashup/q10p2o32/8/)